# How to prevent jquery from removing the <script> tags

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

How do I prevent the default behaviour of jquery stripping out my JS?

```
function callBackFunctionLoadPage(data)
{
    var data = $(data).find('#content');
    alert($(data).html());
    $("#content").html(data);
    $("#page").fadeTo(100,1);
}
function loadPage(url,parm)
{
    //alert(url);
    loadNextBackInPage_URL = url;
    $("#page").fadeTo(100,.2);
    $.post(url,parm,callBackFunctionLoadPage);
}
```

In my code I want the  tags but jquery strips them out:

Original code:

```
<div id="content">
            <div class="post">
                    <h1 class="title"><a href="#">Kannada on campus</a> - photos</h1>
                    <p class="meta">&nbsp;</p>
                    <div class="entry">
                      <p>&nbsp;</p>

              <div id="gallery">
                                      <img src="images/gallery/daya_240909_byreg1.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/Group 2.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/IMG00216-20101025-2001.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/kamal-hassan-in-kannada-02.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/kannada2.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/Nayantara-Kannada.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019502.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019603.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019643.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019644.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/Zee-Kannada-Presents-Rajotsava.jpg">
                                    </div>

<script src="galleria/galleria-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
     $("#gallery").galleria({
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    });
</script>
          </div>
                    <p class="links">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
```

But From jquery:

```
<div id="content">
            <div class="post">
                    <h1 class="title"><a href="#">Kannada on campus</a> - photos</h1>
                    <p class="meta">&nbsp;</p>
                    <div class="entry">
                      <p>&nbsp;</p>

              <div id="gallery">
                                      <img src="images/gallery/daya_240909_byreg1.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/Group 2.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/IMG00216-20101025-2001.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/kamal-hassan-in-kannada-02.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/kannada2.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/Nayantara-Kannada.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019502.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019603.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019643.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019644.jpg">
                                                <img src="images/gallery/Zee-Kannada-Presents-Rajotsava.jpg">
                                    </div>

         </div>
                    <p class="links">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
```

**EDIT**

Here is my actual html page that's getting loaded

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Kannada on campus</title>

<meta name="keywords" content="" />

<link rel="icon" href="images/icon.jpg"/>

<meta name="description" content="" />

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

</head>

<div id="box"><a href="http://twitter.com/bedupako" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Follow us on twitter" longdesc="http://twitter.com/bedupako" border="0" /></a> <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/Bedupako" target="_blank"><img src="images/youtube.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Follow us on twitter" longdesc="http://www.youtube.com/user/Bedupako" border="0" /></a> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/BEDUPAKO/301073813491?ref=ts" target="_blank"><img src="images/Facebook Product  Profile.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Follow us on twitter" longdesc="http://www.facebook.com/pages/BEDUPAKO/301073813491?ref=ts" border="0" /></a> <a href="http://www.orkut.com/Community?cmm=98290522" target="_blank"><img src="images/orkut.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Follow us on twitter" longdesc="http://www.orkut.com/Community?cmm=98290522" border="0" /></a>

  <!--end box-->

</div>

<body>

<!-- start header -->

<div id="header">

    <div id="search"></div>

</div>

<div id="logo">

    <h1><a href="#">Kannada on campus</a></h1><br /><br />

    <h2>Kannada kali, uddaraaagi. Baai muchhikondu bhashe maatadi.</h2>

    </div>

<!-- end header -->

<hr />

<!-- start page -->

<div id="page">

    <div id="menu">

        <ul>

            <li><a href="?p=ho" onclick="javascript:loadPage('?p=ho',null);return false;">Home</a></li>

            <li><a href="?p=e" onclick="javascript:loadPage('?p=e',null);return false;">Events</a></li>

            <li><a href="?p=ph" onclick="javascript:loadPage('?p=ph',null);return false;">Photos</a></li>

            <li><a href="?p=ab" onclick="javascript:loadPage('?p=ab',null);return false;">About</a></li>

            <li><a href="?p=cu" onclick="javascript:loadPage('?p=cu',null);return false;">Contact Us</a></li>

            <li><a href="other_files/change_lang.php?l=k&r=%2Fkoc%2F%3Fp%3Dph">&#3221;&#3240;&#3277;&#3240;&#3233;</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>  <!-- start content -->



    <div id="content">

        <div class="post">

            <h1 class="title"><a href="#">Kannada on campus</a> - photos</h1>

            <p class="meta">&nbsp;</p>

            <div class="entry">

              <p>&nbsp;</p>



              <div id="gallery">

                                      <img src="images/gallery/daya_240909_byreg1.jpg">

                                                <img src="images/gallery/Group 2.jpg">

                                                <img src="images/gallery/IMG00216-20101025-2001.jpg">

                                                <img src="images/gallery/kamal-hassan-in-kannada-02.jpg">

                                                <img src="images/gallery/kannada2.jpg">

                                                <img src="images/gallery/Nayantara-Kannada.jpg">

                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019502.jpg">

                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019603.jpg">

                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019643.jpg">

                                                <img src="images/gallery/P1019644.jpg">

                                                <img src="images/gallery/Zee-Kannada-Presents-Rajotsava.jpg">

                                    </div>



<script src="galleria/galleria-1.2.3.min.js"></script>

<script>

    Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');  

     $("#gallery").galleria({

        width: 500,

        height: 500

    });

</script>

          </div>

            <p class="links">&nbsp;</p>

</div>

    </div>  

    <!-- end content -->



    <!-- start sidebar two -->

    <div id="sidebar2" class="sidebar">

        <ul>

        <li>

        <h2><a href="?p=ev">Register you event</a></h2>

        Tell us if you are conducting any kannada event and we will update it to our audience!

        </li>

            <li>

                <h2>Subscription</h2>



                      <form id="form1" method="post" action="other_files/add_mailing_list.php">

                        <label>

                          Subscribe to our mailing list:

                          <input type="text" name="sub-email" id="sub-email" />

                           <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value=" Add " />

                           <input type="hidden" name="redirect" id="redirect" value="%2Fkoc%2F%3Fp%3Dph" />

                        </label>

                      </form>

                <h2>Current Events</h2>

                <ul>

                              </ul>

              <h2>archives</h2>

                <ul>

                                  <li><a href="?p=de&id=1">test</a></li>

                              </ul>

            </li>

      </ul>

</div>

    <!-- end sidebar two -->

    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>

</div>

<!-- end page -->

<hr />

<!-- start footer -->

<div id="footer">

    <p>&copy;2011 All Rights Reserved. &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; Designed by <a href="http://ajitah.com/" target="_blank">Ajitah</a> | <a href="humans.txt">humans.txt</a></p>

</div>

<!-- end footer --></body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">



  var _gaq = _gaq || [];

  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23549810-1']);

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);



  (function() {

    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

  })();



</script>
```

Comment: which variable in your js code is stripped of SCRIPT Tags? Does the "stripping" happen when inserting the data via .html(data)

Comment: Yes it happens that time itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you do things differently. Firstly, ajax calls are good because they're lightweight, so *instead* of loading a whole page, you can just grab the updated data and inject it where necessary. If you're getting a giant set of markup including scripts you're essentially using ajax to do a normal http page request. That's like looking at the fast line in the supermarket (10 items or less) and seeing it move faster than the isle you're currently standing in, so you move there. But if you do that for every request, you end up turning the fast lane into a normal lane.

Getting javascript code from the server to execute is usually a sign that you're not thinking correctly about the problem, since your mixing domains horribly.

Firstly, why not just have a function that executes every time you ajax the next page/gallery in? Why do you need to get the code from the server? In accordance with my first point, why not just get an array of new filenames and build the new gallery from those?

If for some reason you feel you want to continue this way anyway (I should point out at this point that executing code in such a manner is not just bad practise but unsafe in certain circumstances), you can extract the code and eval it:

Assuming there's only one block of code, and it's wrapped in `<script></script>` (which is not taking into account all sorts of whitespace and funny characters):

```
function callBackFunctionLoadPage(data)
{
    ...
    eval(data.match(/<script>(.*)<\/script>/im)[1]);
}
```

**UPDATE**

jquery strips out the javascript but it still executes it:

```
$('#content').html('<div><script>alert("hello, world!");</script></div>');
```

So there is almost no reason to want the script tags themselves if their content is already executed...

**UPDATE 2 (for non-believers)**

```
var scriptDiv = $('<div><span></span><script>alert("boom!");</script></div>');
alert("not yet"); // the above is created but not executed until added to the DOM
$('body').append(scriptDiv); // there you go, proof that it is executed
alert(scriptDiv.html()); // to prove that the script was stripped
```

Comment: You are right, But what i am doing here is loading a part of the page called content. I am not using this to display a gallery. I am just using this code to get the gallery in the page at first place. i.e a part of the page i am loading from ... not the gallery

Comment: @footy, `#content` sounds like it contains the contents of the page, making it for all intents and purposes, the whole page.

Comment: Its not getting updated actually. The script arranges the photos in a good looking manner. But without script being executed its not working now. It just comes in a column.

Comment: @footy, *sigh*, that's why I put the test code up, to demonstrate that it **is** executed. It must have some other issue if it's not working, because the scripts are executed, you can check this yourself with an alert or a log. I'll make an even more explicit update to prove it.

Comment: ok. i really dont know whats wrong. I have added the actual page output that i take and take only the #content part.... can u tell me whats wrong?

Comment: @footy, I'm not going to debug your problem for you. My answer certainly satisfies the question asked. I suggest you add an alert and prove to yourself that the code is executing. Then go through each part step by step and see what isn't working. If you're lucky, you will realise that my first point is 200% right, and that the way you're doing things is wrong and hard, and you should not be importing large amounts of html and code with ajax.

Comment: what if the attached javascript has a listener? This javascript content as a whole will get executed when it is attached to the DOM. But will the listener always be executed when its conditions are matched?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using JS's native `innerHTML` ?

```
$("#content").get(0).innerHTML = data;
```

If this works, as davin pointed out, you still have to evaluate the scripts:

```
eval(data.match(/<script>(.*)<\/script>/im)[1]);
```

Loading and evaluating SCRIPT form AJAX should work in general.