# disable jQuery removing javascript tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

Best all,

I'm trying to debug our CMS (what is mostly AJAX) but jQuery removes all the script tags, what makes me unable to debug the JavaScript, how do I disable this behaviour?

I thought I would find it after a simple Google search but no success :(

Thank you,

**EDIT**

my Page before:

```
    <script>
    jQuery(function(){
        inter = null;
    jQuery('#parse').click(function(){
        jQuery('#answer').load(f(),{"POST":jQuery("#POST").val(),"start":((jQuery('#start').val()-1)*10)},function(){
            alert("Burrrnnnnnnn")
            console.log("Laten we is kijken: " + inter);
                clearInterval(inter);
            });
        inter = setInterval(function(){
            jQuery.getJSON("/googlemonster/backend/status-test",function(json){
                setProgressBar(json);
            });


        },200);
        return false;
    });

    });
     function

     function setProgressBar(obj){
        var g;
        jQuery("#progress-bar,#progress-text-alt-wrapper").animate({"width":(((g=obj["%"])==0?1:g)*2) + "px"},{queue:false});
        jQuery("#progress-text,#progress-text-alt").text(obj["%"] + "% " + obj["status"]);
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    #progress-text-alt-wrapper {
        height: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 1%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #progress {
        border: solid black 1px;
        padding: 1px;
        text-align: center;
        height: 20px;
        width: 200px
    }

    #progress-bar {
        background-color: green;
        width: 1%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .progress-bar-text {
        padding-top: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #progress-text {
     color:green;
    }
    #progress-text-alt {
        color:#eee;
    }
    </style>
     Query:
    <input id="POST" type="text" />
    <br>
    Pagina
    <input value="1" id="start"
        type="number" />
    <br>
    <button id="parse">Look</button>
    <div>
        <div id="progress">
            <div id="progress-text-alt-wrapper">
                <div class="progress-bar-text" id="progress-text-alt">0% Nothing</div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-bar-text" id="progress-text">0% Nothing</div>
            <div id="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="answer"></div>
```

The page after

```
<style>
#progress-text-alt-wrapper {
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 1%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#progress {
    border: solid black 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px
}

#progress-bar {
    background-color: green;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
}

.progress-bar-text {
    padding-top: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}

#progress-text {
 color:green;
}
#progress-text-alt {
    color:#eee;
}
</style>
 Query:
<input id="POST" type="text">
<br>
Pagina
<input value="1" id="start" type="number">
<br>
<button id="parse">Look</button>
<div>
    <div id="progress">
        <div id="progress-text-alt-wrapper">
            <div class="progress-bar-text" id="progress-text-alt">0% Nothing</div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-bar-text" id="progress-text">0% Nothing</div>
        <div id="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Comment: "but jQuery removes all the script tags, what makes me unable to debug the JavaScript, how do I disable this behaviour?" -- why do you think so?

Comment: it is, It removes the script tag executes it and its gone

Comment: Need to see the site/code it's affecting. This isn't default behavior but can appear in very weird situations. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532644/how-to-prevent-jquery-from-removing-the-script-tags for a similar sounding incident.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: it doesn't sound realistic :-S

Comment: @zerkms I know :( check the edit

Comment: @RyanMcDonough yes, but that doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: How do you capture the "page after" state?

Comment: @zerkms Chrome got a neat tool called Developer tools, and on the Elements tab

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: what if you remove the code from the script step by step (call by call, function by function) and catch the one that causes such behaviour? ps: this is called [debug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) pps: probably it's not a bad idea to add `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: @zerkms I didn't mean it sarcastic sorry

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Can't append <script> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

Comment: @zerkms still no script tag :(

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: "still" after what? Have you followed my advice and debug your code?

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses can we see the site?

Comment: @zerkms yes, I did delete all the content in the script tag, and did switch from `$.fn.load` , to `$.ajax`

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: I didn't advice to delete ALL THE CONTENT. I proposed to delete it iteratively line by line. That's what a debug process means. And following it you may know what exact call causes that.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough it's intern, and it uses Windows so no

Comment: @zerkms I know what causes it but I want to disable it

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: and how are we supposed to help you if **only you** knows exactly what causes that?

Comment: @zerkms feeela knows it too, its not only me, but I found salvation, writing the code down now

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: feeela's answer is irrelevant to what you've asked and provided in the question.

Comment: these comments wouldn't have gotten out of control if original issue had a properly detailed explanation.

Comment: @charlietfl: I tried my best actually, but OP decided to make some random steps expecting the code to magically work.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: you've fixed something strange that doesn't happen to us ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research I finnaly could fix the problem thanks to the guys here,

I made a little plugin for jQuery for it, now the script tags are not getting, removed but executed.

```
(function($){

    $.fn.loadDebuggable = function(url){

        data = typeof(arguments[1]) == "object"?arguments[1]:{};
        success = arguments[2]||typeof(arguments[1]) == "function"?arguments[1]:function(){};
        return $.ajax(url,{
            "context":this,
            "success":[function(data){
                var div = document.createElement('DIV');
                div.innerHTML = data;
                this[0].innerHTML = "";
                while (div.firstChild) 
                 {
                    this[0].appendChild(div.firstChild);
                    div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
                 };


            },success],
            "type":"GET",
            "data":data
            });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks,

Comment: This is a very strange piece of code. Following the idea that at least I don't use anything like that to do whatever I want with my js tells me you're doing something wrong.

Comment: yes, but you're solving the issue that no one else is experiencing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are right – it is a feature of jQuery to strip out script tags. You need to use the basic JavaScript methods instead.

See: [Can't append <script> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

> Scripts will be evaluated first, and then discarded.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: but what do I need to do then it's an ajax request?

Comment: "You are right – it is a feature of jQuery to strip out script tags." --- this statement is just wrong. Open the current stackoverflow page and see there are `script` tags there. So, not an answer

Comment: This counts for `.append()`, which calls the method `.domManip()` which in turn executes any inline JavaScripts and afterwards remove the script tags. See: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js @line: 311 So you cannot insert scripts by using one of the jQuery DOM manipulation methods.

Comment: @feeela: OP **doesn't** append scripts in runtime. Please have a look at the code in the question and read it once again

Comment: @zerkms You are right, the OP is not losing a word on how the script is inserted to the page; but that would be a valid explanation if the page is loaded via AJAX (as the OP stated in the question).

Comment: @feeela: if so - then question lacks at least the source of the page that loads that one.