# Engineering a better solution than getting a whole HTML document with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I have a webpage that I am working on for a personal project to learn about javascript and web development. The page consists of a menu bar and some content. My idea is, when a link is clicked, to change the content of the page via AJAX, such that I:

1. fetch some new content from a different page,
2. swap out the old content with the new,
3. animate the content change with some pretty javascript visual effects.

I figure that this is a little more efficient than getting a whole document with a standard HTTP GET request, since the browser won't have to fetch the style sheets and scripts sourced in the `<head>` tag of the document. I should also add that I am fetching content solely from documents that are served by my web app that I have created and whose content I am fully aware of.

Anyway, I came across [this answer on an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6532895/1824868) recently, and it got me wondering about the ideal way to engineer a solution that fits the requirements I have given for the web page. The way I see it, there are two solutions, neither of which seem ideal:

1. Configure the back-end (server) from which I am fetching such that it will return content and not the entire page if asked for only content, and then load that content in with AJAX (my current solution), or
2. Get the entire document with AJAX and then use a script to extract the content and load it into the page.

It seems to me that neither solution is not quite right. For 1, it seems that I am splitting logic across two different places: The server has to be configured to serve content if asked for content and the the javascript has to know how to ask for content. For 2, it seems that this is an inappropriate use of AJAX (according to the previously mentioned SO answer), given that I am asking for a whole page and then parsing it, when AJAX is meant to fetch small bits and pieces of information rather than whole documents.

So I am asking: which of these two solutions is better from an engineering perspective? Is there another solution which would be better than either of these two options?

Answer (score 1):

> animate the content change with some pretty javascript visual effects.

Please don't. Anyway, you seem to be looking for a JS MVC framework like [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Using such a framework, you can let the server return *models*, represented in JSON or XML, which a little piece of JS transforms into HTML, using various ways of templating and annotations.

So instead of doing the model-to-HTML translation serverside and send a chunk of HTML to the browser, you just return a list of business objects (say, Addresses) in a way the browser (or rather JS) understands and let Knockout bind that to a grid view, input elements and so on.

Comment: Let's leave aside the discussion of aesthetics (the animation is only a fade out - fade in anyway). What I am looking for is a high-level solution, not necessarily a specific answer like a piece of code or a javascript library. It seems to me that the library you suggested changes the standard MVC model. Maybe moving away from or modifying the MVC model is the way to proceed. But I want to think about this more abstractly and discuss the two solutions I gave before suggesting new solutions or even looking at specific libraries. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You spent more words than I on the animation; it was a joke. I don't know what you mean by changing the MVC model. My answer is broader than a single library suggestion, I mentioned Knockout as an example. The higher-level solution for not sending HTML to the browser is to use a client-side framework that can handle _meaningful data_ as opposed to just Html with its own semantics. A client-side MVC framework is one solution for that, answering your first suggestion. I would never go for the second.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. The way I understand it, traditionally, the model (html) is generated by the server, but this framework moves the model generation to the client-side and adds the additional element of a "view model". That is what I mean by "changing the MVC model".

Comment: @jayhendren if you explain it like that I agree - but please note that HTML is just a markup language, in other words it forms the **view**. The view gets populated with data from the **model**. While you may have model variables printed in your view, that does not make the view the model. You can still use (more or less) the same HTML, you just don't **populate** it serverside but clientside. It really is the difference between printing `<span>$userName</span>` serverside and `<span data-bind="username" />`, where in the latter case you populate it using JS, with a model received as JSON.