# Click handler inside Iframe is not working after content is being inserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

So I'm currently working on a small styleguide application and part of the functionality is that there is a sandbox area where certain modules get loaded into an iframe (to be able to simulate media queries). Now this content is inserted dynamically after the iframe is created along with the relevant styling and scripts.

The non event handler scripts work fine for example an alert box but the click handlers don't seem to be functional. Jquery is loaded in just fine so I've ruled that out.

This is a sample of the code being inserted

```
    <!-- Accordion-->
<div class="accordion module-suggestions col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pull-right hidden-xs">
            <h4>Most popular</h4>
            <div class="accordion-section active">
                <ul>
                    <li>Why your CCTV could land you in jail<span class="result-type case-study"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>How to measure performance of SMEs<span class="result-type guides"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>How to measure performance <span class="result-type checklist"></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h4>Most recent</h4>
            <div class="accordion-section">
                <ul>
                    <li>Why your CCTV could land you in jail<span class="result-type case-study"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>How to measure performance of SMEs<span class="result-type guides"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>How to measure performance <span class="result-type checklist"></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h4>Recommended</h4>
            <div class="accordion-section">
                <ul>
                    <li>Why your CCTV could land you in jail<span class="result-type case-study"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>How to measure performance of SMEs<span class="result-type guides"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>How to measure performance <span class="result-type checklist"></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- / Accordion  -->

<script>
function accordion() {
    var accordion = $('.accordion h4');
    var accordionSection = $('div.accordion-section');
    $(accordion).on("click", function(e) { 

        if (!$(this).next(accordionSection).is(":visible")) {
             $(accordionSection).is(":visible") && $(accordionSection).slideUp();   
             $(this).next(accordionSection).slideDown();  
        }
    });
}
accordion();
</script>
```

Just to clarify, the code is being put directly inside the iframe's HTML, I'm not calling it from it's parent.

The code responsible for inserting the html/js into the iframe:

iframePreview.contents().find('html').html(  libraryScripts + '\n' + moduleHtmlAndJs);

Any idea how I can make these click handlers functional?

Comment: where are you calling accordion()??

Comment: the whole content inside the script tag is being run inside the iframe.

Comment: Delegate click event: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this by using slideToggle and access the closest accordion-section within the handler.

Try this:

```
function accordion() {
    $('.accordion').on("click","h4", function() { 
          var accordionSection = $(this).next('div.accordion-section');
          $(accordionSection).slideToggle();  
    });
}
accordion();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7fpt87yv/

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear but the issue isn't my accordion code as that works just fine outside of the iframe. The issue is the click handlers aren't even responding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `.html()` strips out `<script>` tags.

[How to prevent jquery from removing the <script> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532644/how-to-prevent-jquery-from-removing-the-script-tags)

Try to use `.innerHTML` instead:

```
iframePreview.contents().find('html').[0].innerHTML =  libraryScripts + '\n' + moduleHtmlAndJs;
```

Comment: my accordion code works perfectly fine outside of the iframe. It's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than injecting your script into the iframe couldn't you create the function at global level on the iframe contentWindow itself?

For example:

```
iframePreview.contentWindow.accordion = function(){
      $('.accordion').on("click","h4", function() { ... etc...});
}
```

Then call that function once you've inserted your html:

```
 iframePreview.contentWindow.accordion();
```

So - you set the function from the parent window on the iFrame and call it from the parent once the HTML is in place.